# What's the glowing thing in Commodore Paris' office?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[image]

When Paris tells Kirk, "It's not uncommon, you know. To get lost in the vastness of space," there's this massive glowing thing hovering over her desk. Did something in that scene, that I missed, explain what it was and why it was currently running? Was it some kind of library? Or art?

Comment: Wasn't that the nebula they were talking about?

Comment: Down-voting without a comment is like kissing a dog on the lips.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine someone just thought the answer was too blatantly obvious to warrant a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the dialogue happening on screen, the "*massive glowing thing*" in Commodore Paris' office would appear to be a scan/map of the nearby [Necro Cloud Nebula](http://trekmovie.com/2016/06/30/pegg-jung-talk-beyond-with-star-trek-magazine-spoilers%E2%80%8F/) and surrounding space.

I've added stage direction in [brackets] to show what's happening on screen.

> **Cdre Paris:** *We tracked her stranded ship to a sector of uncharted nebula. Here* [she nods at an area of the glowing map]*, two hundred
>   and ten, mark fourteen.*
>
> **Kirk:** *Uh, long range scan?* [Kirk operates the controls at one of the consoles]
>
> **Cdre Paris:** *No data. The nebula is too dense.* [The nebula enlarges in the hologram] *It's uncharted space.*